# Firefox extension content script does not load and append HTML

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Everything below works in a Chrome extension but silently fails when ported to Firefox on:

1. loading the `test.html` unless I remove `<style></style>` from it
2. appending the `#test_element` to the body

Do styles have to go into a separate file for Firefox extension? Why does `append()` fail?

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/html/test.html'), function(data) {
        // not called unless style element is removed from HTML
        // and never actually appended if it is removed
        $(document.body).append($.parseHTML(data));
    });
});
```

**test.html**

```
<style></style>
<div id="test_element">
    <p>my name is cow</p>
</div>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",

    "icons": {
        "64": "icons/icon-64.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "idle"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["lib/jquery.js", "src/test.js"]
        }
    ],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "html/test.html"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Might be related: [style and script tags in HTML body... why not?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1362039)

Comment: @wOxxOm in the case when Firefox doesn't append the loaded elements there's no `<style>` tag.

Comment: *Please* don't load jQuery into **every** page (`content_scripts` with your `matches`) unless you **need** to.  jQuery is 85kiB of minimized code. This is a significant burden with which to saddle *every single page*. What of those of us who have 100's of tabs open? While it's possible you really *need* to load jQuery, it's more likely that you are doing so for the convenience of saving a couple/few hundred characters in your own code by not using vanilla JavaScript. If that's the case (it is in the code in the question), doing so is a *very* poor trade-off from your user's point of view.

Comment: @Makyen right, I used it before for more complex pages like the extension's popup menu and forgot about the 100-tab case. Will update the solution and my code, thanks!

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not falling silently to me but gives me:

```
  XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
  Location: https://www.google.gr/
  Line Number 2, Column 1
```

This is because it is not a valid XML document (one root element only should exists).

My way to make it work is the following:

**test.html**: (Make it valid)

```
  <div>
    <style></style>
    <div id="test_element">
        <p>my name is cow</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**test.js**: (Use XMLSerializer)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/html/test.html'), function(data) {
          res = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);
          $(document.body).append(res);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, `getURL()` was indeed failing because of the two root nodes. `XMLSerializer` worked in Firefox but failed in Chrome with `Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`. I solved it by `$.parseXML(data)` but then it stops working in Firefox. :) Still searching for a universal solution...

Comment: I have implemented this way in firefox. And the other way in chrome. If you find something cross browser please let me know.

Comment: The main difference is that `$.get` from the HTML file returns a raw string in Chrome but `XMLDocument` in Firefox. Therefore, it's possible to instantly `.append(data)` in Chrome but Firefox requires `.serializeToString(data)` first. So I'm just checking if `data` is string. Thanks for help!

Comment: Updated the question with a cross-browser solution in vanilla JS. :D

Answer (score 0):

For #1: see the solution by Christos. For #2: `$.get()` returns a string in Chrome but `XMLDocument` in Firefox (that must be serialized with `serializeToString()` before appending). Anyway, I removed jQuery to make the content script lighter (by the way, `$(document).ready()` is not required because by default content scripts are injected after DOM is ready):

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onload = function(data) {
    httpRequest.onload = null;

    var template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = data.target.responseText;

    var element = template.content.firstChild;
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}

httpRequest.open('GET', chrome.extension.getURL('/html/test.html'));
httpRequest.send();
```