# Web Extension script jQuery load html div

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on my first web extension and I would like to load a predefined html to the targeted page.

In manifest I added "index.html" to `web_accessible_resources`.

In the content script I try to load this html to some other div like so:

```
$("#divTestRectangle").load("index.html", function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        console.log(response);
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

And I get "The URI is malformed" error from xhr.statusText.

What am I missing? Or perhaps there is another alternative? I don't want to use "hardcoded" string variable object because it doesn't feel right and elegant.

Edit:

manifest.json:

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "youtube-test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "index.html"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "https://www.youtube.com/watch*" ],
      "css": [ "style.css" ],
      "js": [ "jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "jquery-ui.min.js", "main.js" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

main.js:

```
$(function () {

    var htmlRectangle = '<div id="divTestRectangle"></div>';

    $("#ticker-content").prepend(htmlRectangle);

    $("#divTestRectangle").load("index.html", function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";

            console.log(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });

    $("#divTestRectangle").draggable({});
});
```

Edit:

answer below

Comment: Can you please enhance you question with a sample main.js and a manifest, in order to be a functional example and make it easier to point the problem?

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas Edited, thanks.

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039375/firefox-extension-content-script-does-not-load-and-append-html/). You need to call `chrome.extension.getURL`.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked, even though I'm testing it on Firefox, so this part I don't understand, but for now I'm just happy that it works. You can make it an answer and I will accept it...

Comment: @Makyen not at all, read my previous comment.

Comment: @Makyen see edit. I'd say the question and the answer is different then your proposed "duplicate", I just got a hint from the line from that linked question. My main problem was that I didn't use chrome.extension.getURL.

Comment: @Makyen yes, that makes sense. But I was waiting for Christos to answer...

Comment: Waiting for Christos to answer is a good thing. I usually recommend pinging them and waiting at least 24 hours, and/or checking their profile to see if they've been on SO in that time. At this point, they've been on SO at least within the last 3 hours (of this comment being posted). You've given them several days, which is plenty. I think you've done the correct thing and gone ahead and answered. Mentioning that you got direction from a comment is a good thing. Although, I did not contribute to you finding the actual answer, so there's no need to mention me, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is to change the line

```
$("#divTestRectangle").load("index.html", function (response, status, xhr) {
```

to

```
$("#divTestRectangle").load(chrome.extension.getURL("index.html"), function (response, status, xhr) {
```

Thanks to comments by @ChristosPapoulas and @Makyen.